# Angular JS and addthis eventhandlers

Tags: angularjs, addthis

I'm using Angular for the first time on a large project and one of the requirements is that we use AddThis for social sharing for articles.  But in addition to the *AddThis* sharing, we want to track the share events in google analytics.

So what I want to do is add the *AddThis*

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_16x16_style">
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=XXXXX"></script>
```

and in the controller, add an event handler as described in their docs
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api-#configuration-sharing

```
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.open', eventHandler);
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.close', eventHandler);
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.share', eventHandler);
```

The problem, is that I can't seem to get a reference to the addthis object in the $scope of the controller.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this either via directive or some other trick to do a document.ready and getting a reference to the addthis object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addthis` is a property of `window` and must be visible in any scope, however I guess that `type` parameter of `addEventListener` is not evaluated inside addthis_widget.js

Did you try this?

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_16x16_style">
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=XXXXX"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.open', eventHandler);
    addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.close', eventHandler);
    addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.share', eventHandler);
<script>
```

That way events should be applied each time you reload the widget.

If does't help, you can wrap it into a directive like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654055/2331982). Try to add your listeners inside the directive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I ended up doing something very similar.  I had to wrap the addEventListener calls within the link function with `element.ready(registerShareListeners)`.  This made sure that the rendering was complete before attaching the share listeners.