# AddThis not playing nice with Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, addthis

My site recently had the social buttons break without any changes to the code.

I'm using AddThis for the sharing buttons, with Angular on the front-end.

I'm passing in the data for each entry using

```
<div data-addthis-toolbox ng-tap="socialShare = !socialShare" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"
```

This appears to be working because it renders in DevTools

Comment: hmm.. did you upgrade your angular.js version recently? what is "data-addthis-toolbox" your own directive? if so, can you share the code so we can look at it? what version of angular.js are you currently(!) using ? Why are you using ng-tap instead of ngTouch ngClick event?

Comment: Also - did you check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321095/angular-js-and-addthis-eventhandlers)?

Comment: @alonisser Which answer? I have not changed my angular.js version, as mentioned in the post, I haven't touched the code at all recently. I'm using Angular v1.2.4. I've edited the post to add the addthis-toolbox directive. I'm using ng-tap because the touch event has a 300ms delay on touch devices (not sure if they've changed that afterwards).

Comment: @theintellects the accepted answer in the link he included in his comment

Comment: @thescientist Oh I see it now. Wasn't there when I replied. I have looked at it, doesn't seem to have to do with my problem.

Comment: I guess the change is in addThis js snippet, since you load it from their site, you can't really know. The problem may have to do with the directive priority - try setting it high (1000) or low (-1) and see if it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is from some change in addThis js snippet. but we really can't know. Two suggestion that might help:

1. play with the directive priority (I don't think it's the issue, but you should rule this out)
2. replace `data-title="{{article.title}} via discoverwiki.com"` with:

   ng-attr-data-title="{{article.title}} via discoverwiki.com"

as explained **[here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)** (I believe this is the problem..)

Comment: When I try replacing `data-title` with `ng-attr-data-title` it just ends up using the title of my site as the social-sharing title, instead of the individual articles.