# AngularJS and Adsense - Ads stop populating after a couple page views

Tags: angularjs, adsense

I built my site with AngularJS and recently added Adsense to it. If I go to the homepage I will see 3 ads (great), and then if I click on a detail page I see 1 ad (great), but then I go back to the homepage and I will only see 1 out of the 3 ads loaded and then no matter what page I go to next the ad div is blank.

Does anyone know how to fix this. I saw one other thread on StackOverflow asking this question but the only solution there isn't working.

[AngularJS and Adsense ads not loaded on route change (up to 3 ads for the entire app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709973/angularjs-and-adsense-ads-not-loaded-on-route-change-up-to-3-ads-for-the-entire/30386854)

Comment: this is a known issue with AdSense.  Technically using AdSense in a SPA is against the TOS.  It is *possible* that you might find someone who has a workaround, but the real answer to your issue can only be provided by google.  Best to contact them directly; there are a half dozen inquiries in google groups related to the issue.

Comment: using any workarounds that might be offered here are also not guaranteed to not result in suspensions by google for TOS violations, so the usefulness of any workarounds is limited.

Comment: i'm surprised that Google hasn't fixed this issue, since they maintain Angular. i can't find any posts online about people getting banned for using adsense in a SPA so I think I'm alright with using Adsense, but I guess I don't want to do any 'tricks' to get adsense to work properly because I don't want banned. I can't believe though their isn't some legal way to get this to work.

Comment: TOS doesn't have anything to do with legality, it has to do with a service provider allowing you to use their service based on the conditions they set.  The people within google who maintain adsense don't have anything to do with the people who work with angular, and the SPA restriction is not limited to angular, but all SPA frameworks.  They can't very well create an angular specific fix and leave the users of other frameworks out in the cold....