# Angular Directive for Add this

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I've created this directive for addthis plugin but it only displays/renders the buttons once in a while, not everytime...

```
.directive('addThis', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        image: '='
    },
    replace: true,

    templateUrl: Directory.url + '/templates/_addthis.html',
    link: function(scope, elm){
        console.log('Create addthis button');
    }   
}
```

})

template code:

```
<ul class="image-actions">
<li><a class="addthis_button_facebook" addthis:url="{{image.link}}" fb:like:href="{{image.link}}"  addthis:title="{{image.post.post_title}}"></a></li>
<li><a class="addthis_button_twitter" tw:url="{{image.link}}"  addthis:title="{{image.post.post_title}}"></a></li>
<li><a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share" addthis:url="{{image.link}}"  addthis:title="{{image.post.post_title}}"></a></li>
<li><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share" addthis:url="{{image.link}}"  addthis:title="{{image.post.post_title}}"></a></li>
<li>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact" addthis:url="{{image.link}}"  addthis:title="{{image.post.post_title}}"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style" addthis:url="{{image.link}}"  addthis:title="{{image.post.post_title}}"></a>
</li>
```

Grateful for help... i'd like to be able to control when it renders... or somehow inject it into the scope...?

Comment: Look at the firebug console. Is there any error. Is the content generated at all?

Comment: it gets generated sometimes, but doesnt ttrigger any error when it doesnt work..

Comment: its mainly when i use angular router navigation that it doesnt get rendered

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs and AddThis social plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593039/angularjs-and-addthis-social-plugin)

Comment: The other poster is not really doing anything dynamic, but merely including the addthis code in a directive, i want the directive to create the buttons, for more control...